# Hexa decimal interpretation

Tags: bluetooth, hex

I am trying to connect a pedometer watch to my phone with bluetooth and want to read the steps from it to an app I have made. The connection is made successfully and I am able to read the data from the watch but I am not so clear how to interpret it.

Below is the document,

**Eigenvalue content:**

```
(1) all the eigenvalue content inside the endian order are small endian order.

(2) current_pedometer_measurement
    The value of the current_pedometer_measurement consists of four parts
    Value type description
    Flag Uint8 0x01: Number of Steps (Required)
    0x02: Distance (optional)
    0x04: Calories (optional)
    Such as 0x05 that contains the number of steps and calories
    StepCount Uint24 The number of steps
    StepDistancer Uint24 How far, in meters
    StepCalorie Uint24 calories

    Description:

    1.  Distance and calories are optional, may or may not appear
        If only the number of steps, then the value is: 01 (steps) 10 27 00 (1 million steps)
        If there are steps and distances, then the value is: 03 (number of steps, distance) 10 27 00 (1 million steps) 70 17 00 (6 km)
        Other cases and so on.
    2.  Time value to mobile phone time as the standard, that is, the moment the phone receives the data that is the time of this data.

(3) target

    The target value is
    Value type description
    Flag Uint8 0x01: Number of Steps (Required)
    StepCount Uint24 The number of steps

    Description:
    1. If the target is 10,000 steps, then the value is: 01 (steps) 10 27 00 (1 million steps)
    2. If the device writes to the target value, the device is updated. If the device updates the target value, notify the phone.
```

The reading I am getting from the pedometer watch is:

```
[7, 64, 1, 0, 144, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0]
```

Can anyone help me to interpret it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data appears to follow your description exactly.  The first byte is the flag field and in this case it indicates that all 3 measurement types are being reported. Or`ing bits 1 and 2 and 3 equals 7.

The next 9 bytes are the 3 24-bit data values, where 64,1,0 are steps, 144,0,0 are distance, and 24,0,0 are calories.  How you convert the bytes is a bit confusing, but if you use little-endian format and assume you printed them in decimal do these values make sense?

> ```
> Steps:    00 01 64  = 0x000140 = 320 
> Distance: 00 00 144 = 0x000090 = 144
> Calories: 00 00 24  = 0x000018 = 24
> ```

From your examples above the values are probably in hex:

> ```
> 10 27 00 = 0x002710 = 10000
> 70 17 00 = 0x001770 = 6000
> ```

Hope that helps!

grace

Comment: Yes it was 6000 steps I had set for target. I will study it more.